# Express not finding/using layout

Tags: node.js, layout, express

I am trying to use express and render a layout.jade my directory tree is pretty standard.

```
├── apps
│   └── fridge_face
│       ├── routes.coffee
│       └── views
|           └── index.jade
├── server.js
└── views
    ├── layout.jade
    └── stylesheets
        └── style.styl
```

In my routes.coffee when I render index.jade everything words fine, but layout is not rendered.  I have tried moving layout into `apps/fridge_face/views/` but that was not successful.

I have done no layout configuration.

Here is my

#### layout.jade

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    title 'What is up'
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    != body
```

#### routes.coffee

```
routes = (app) ->
  app.get '/', (req, res) ->
    Word.once 'wordsFetched', (params) ->
      res.render "#{__dirname}/views/index",
        layout: true
        words: params.map (word) -> word.word

    Word.getWords()


module.exports = routes
```

#### server.js config

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express['static'](__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

As you can see nothing that could or would make the layout not render... what am I doing wrong how do I get express to find my layout

### Edit

---

I know I am making this question super long but adding some developments. First

When I remove the `!=` from the layouts in both directories, nothing changes. My view is still rendered layout free.

When I add

```
app.set('view options', {
  layout: false
});
```

and then explicitly render my layout in my view with either

```
layout: "#{__dirname}/views/layout"
# OR
layout: "layout"
# OR
layout: true
```

Nothing happens and the view is rendered layout free...

Comment: your config seems right. What version of express are you using?

Comment: @Rajat 3.0.0beta6, installed with `npm install express --save`

Comment: I am at v2.5.8 and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using outdated code with the new express version. Please see http://github.com/visionmedia/jade for the new usage of templating system.

Comment: The express code I have in server.js was generated with their binary, which part is outdated?

Answer (score 6):

As someone above said, you're using version 3.0 which got rid of layout & partials & lets the templating engine handle that. Here's the answer via the migration wiki:

"To get back layout functionality with EJS you can use [express-partials](https://github.com/publicclass/express-partials) or ejs-locals."

(from https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x )

I ended up using express-partials & it worked exactly as it is in their example. I was unable to post the link to ejs-locals as I don't have enough reputation yet but you can find it on the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly specifying the path to your layout file when you call `render`. There's an example in the express docs:

```
res.render('page', { layout: __dirname + '/../../mylayout.jade' });
```

My guess is there's different logic in express/jade depending on whether the view name is unqualified or specified as a filesystem path.

Answer (score 0):

If layout doesn't work you can try with partial, I'm using ejs :

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
 res.render('layout.ejs', { layout:false,
   locals : {
        body: '../apps/index.ejs' ,
        name : "Daniel"
 }});
});
```

And in layout.ejs:

```
<html>
...
<%-partial(body)%>
<html>
```

In index.ejs :

```
<h1>Hola</h1>
<%=name%>
```